# how to create a floating button

Tags: android, button, floating-action-button

i am trying to learn how to create a floating button, so i referred to this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/ but the problem is when i run the App, i receive the below
posted logcat error, and line number 26 refers to this line

please have a look athe files posted below and the error message i receive, and please let me know how to solve item

**code**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.floating_button);
```

**floating_button**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.bestandlayout_00.ActMain">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/act_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**actMain.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.bestandlayout_00.ActMain">

<include
    layout="@layout/status"></include>

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/meine_vertaege"></include>
```

**gradle app**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bestandlayout_00"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

}

**styles.xml**:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">100dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">?android:attr/listDivider</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

**logcat error**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.bestandlayout_00, PID: 26153
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bestandlayout_00/com.example.bestandlayout_00.ActMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.example.bestandlayout_00.ActMain.onCreate(ActMain.java:25)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 0):

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+ added support for tinting widgets on devices running pre android 5.1 (API Level 21). To make use of it make sure you extend or set the AppCompat Theme and use app:backgroundTint instead of android:backgroundTint.

Example:

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab"

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="16dp"
android:src="@drawable/icon"
app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
app:borderWidth="0dp" />
```

and Please change it into AppCompatActivity if you use Activity. Probably it becomes the error when it is Activity

Answer (score 0):

Add this to gradle dependencies

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: i just kept my gradle:app as it is posted above, and just modified the 'com.android.support:desige' to be 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'..actually now the app works despite the line 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0' is underlined with red..do u know why it is underlined with red??

Comment: your support library version is lower so it shows in red..compileSdkVersion 25 ... try matching it with compilesdkversion